How can I have a private field in Dart on a class and use dart_mappable?
I want to have a class with a private field in Dart to, for example, be able to define a non-obvious setter. How can I make it work with dart_mappable?
For example:
    import 'package:dart_mappable/dart_mappable.dart';
    
    part 'private_field.mapper.dart';
    
    @MappableClass()
    class PrivateField with PrivateFieldMappable {
      String _name;
    
      PrivateField(String aName) {
        name = aName;
      }
    
      set name(String name) {
        if (name.isEmpty) {
          throw Exception('Name cannot be empty');
        }
        _name = name;
      }
    
      String get name => _name;
    }

This code results in the following error from dart run build_runner:

Class PrivateField defines constructor parameters that could not be
resolved against any field or getter in the class. This won't break
your code, but may lead to unexpected behaviour when serializing this
class. Also '.copyWith()' won't work on these parameters.
The following problematic parameters were detected:

aName: Cannot find field or getter related to this parameter.

Please make sure every constructor parameter can be resolved to a
field or getter.

Despite not being optimal, I tried also
    import 'package:dart_mappable/dart_mappable.dart';
    
    part 'private_field.mapper.dart';
    
    @MappableClass()
    class PrivateField with PrivateFieldMappable {
      String _name;
    
      PrivateField(this._name);
    
      set name(String name) {
        if (name.isEmpty) {
          throw Exception('Name cannot be empty');
        }
        _name = name;
      }
    
      String get name => _name;
    }

just to get:

Named parameters can't start with an underscore.

error message inside private_field.mapper.dart.
What is the recommended way to use private fields in Dart when using dart_mappable on the same class?

I just tried an apparently simple solution to this issue. Change the above code to:
import 'package:dart_mappable/dart_mappable.dart';

part 'private_field.mapper.dart';

@MappableClass()
class PrivateField with PrivateFieldMappable {
  late String _name;

  PrivateField(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  set name(String name) {
    if (name.isEmpty) {
      throw Exception('Name cannot be empty');
    }
    _name = name;
  }

  String get name => _name;
}

The main change is on the constructor. To guarantee that the "name" assignment in the constructor is done through the setter and dart_mappable deals correctly with the _name parameter I had to:

change the constructor parameter name to "name", i.e., the same as the the setter and getter names;
use the ugly** "this.name = name" code inside the constructor;
change the "String name;" property to "late String name;"

** I don't like having both the parameters and the setter with the same name as it gets easy to use the wrong entity and you need to explicitely diferentiate "this.name" (the setter) from "name" (the constructor parameter).
